# How to substract 2 dem.tiff rasters through GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, dem

I'm a beginner in GDAL and don't understand the logic of it work completly.

I have a folder with 2 DEM-tif files and I need to do this:

```
gdal_calc.py -A D:WORK\gdal\dem05.tif -B D:WORK\gdal\dem31_size05.tif --outfile=demdiff_0531
```

The DEM have different sizes and different pixel sizes (so I'm getting errors), but the same location and the same coordinate systems.

```
"Error! Dimensions of file D:WORK\gdal\dem31.tif (25521, 21308) are different from other files (28986, 13493). Cannot proceed"
```

And when I did "gdal_translate -outsize" made them the same size I got this:

```
– Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 335, in <module> main() 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 332, in main doit(opts, args) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 168, in doit myOut.SetGeoTransform(myFiles[0].GetGeoTransform()) 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'
```

---

I will have different DEMs in the future so I need to know how to do it in general.

Comment: If you say "so I'm getting errors" please include the error message. What research have you done on resizing/resampling in order to fit the pixel sizes?

Comment: "Error! Dimensions of file D:WORK\gdal\dem31.tif (25521, 21308) are different from other files (28986, 13493).  Cannot proceed"    And when I did "gdal_translate -outsize" and made them the same size I got this:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 335, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 332, in main
    doit(opts, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 168, in doit
    myOut.SetGeoTransform(myFiles[0].GetGeoTransform())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/341223/edit) button on your question, since this is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If those rasters have slightly different extent you have to match those first. To do so find out the extent of both files by executing gdalinfo for both files.

```bsh
gdalinfo dem05.tif
gdalinfo dem31_size05.tif
```

Take the smallest and largest x and y values of corner coordinates and use those as your new extent.
Then "reproject" both files to this combined extent using the same resolution.

```bsh
gdalwarp -te xmin ymin xmax ymax -tr 0.5 dem05.tif dem05_combined_extent.tif
gdalwarp -te xmin ymin xmax ymax -tr 0.5 dem31_size05.tif dem31_size05_combined_extent.tif
```

Then you should be able to perform the calculation:

```bsh
gdal_calc.py -A dem05_combined_extent.tif -B dem31_size05_combined_extent.tif --calc="A-B" --outfile=demdiff_0531.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

Gdal is not yet supported for processing raster with different dimension, although somebody has submit the ticket for enhancement [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4370#no2)

You can try to used the script provided in above link to do calculation [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/attachment/ticket/4370/gdal_calc.patch.py)